# opt.curve_fit with only one parameter

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I'm having trouble fitting a curve with only one parameter using `scipy.opt.curve_fit`:

```
import scipy.optimize as opt
import numpy as np

def func(T):
    return 76.881324*np.exp((-L)/(8.314*T))

best_params, cov_matrix = opt.curve_fit(func, xdata = x, ydata = y, p0=[])
```

I have arrays of values, `x` (T in the below eq) and `y` (P) that I'm trying to fit to the equation 
[image]

but it seems it wants `func()` to have more than one argument. How do I fix this?

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you gave values for the x and y arrays. Could you provide a minimal, reproducible example? Cf. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. In the meantime I added import and alias for scipy.optimize and numpy to the code snippet.

Comment: The parameter to be fit must be an argument of the model function.  Change the signature of the function to `def func(T, L)`. That's assuming `x` holds `T` values, and you are trying to find the best value for `L`.  If `x` holds `L` values, and you are trying to find `T`, the signature must be `def funct(L, T)`.

Comment: Also change `p0` to be a value that you expect to be a reasonable guess for the parameter that you are fitting.

Comment: ...or at least do not put the `kwarg` with an empty list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a graphical Python fitter using your equation with some test data. Replace the example data with your own and you should be done.

[image: plot]

```
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

xData = numpy.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.0, 6.6, 7.7])
yData = numpy.array([1.1, 20.2, 30.3, 60.4, 50.0, 60.6, 70.7])


def func(T, L):
    return 76.881324*numpy.exp((-L)/(8.314*T))


# all "1.0" is the same as the scipy defaults
initialParameters = numpy.array([1.0])

# curve fit the test data
fittedParameters, pcov = curve_fit(func, xData, yData, initialParameters)

modelPredictions = func(xData, *fittedParameters) 

absError = modelPredictions - yData

SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(yData))

print('Parameters:', fittedParameters)
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = func(xModel, *fittedParameters)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```